# Inconsistent information regarding amount of answers for a question to become Community Wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, help-pages

The amount of answers to turn a question into a community wiki is listed differently in two places:

- https://superuser.com/help/privileges/community-wiki mentions "**30** answers".
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) mentions "**15** on Super User"

It looks like the latter is the correct value, therefore the former should be corrected.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant since auto CW is removed

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed, but... Due to the way privilege wikis work, it means we'll have to remember to update this one separately every time we change the master copy on Meta SO.

If this becomes a headache, a way to pull that value from the site settings would be necessary.